# Ruby CSV: Comparison of columns (from two csvs), write new column in one

Tags: ruby, csv, cross-reference

I've searched and haven't found a method for this particular conundrum. I have two CSV files of data that sometimes relate to the same thing. Here's an example:

CSV1 (500 lines):

```
date,reference,amount,type
10/13/2015,,1510.40,sale
10/13/2015,,312.90,sale
10/14/2015,,928.50,sale
10/15/2015,,820.25,sale
10/12/2015,,702.70,credit
```

CSV2 (20000 lines):

```
reference,date,amount
243534985,10/13/2015,312.90
345893745,10/15/2015,820.25
086234523,10/14/2015,928.50
458235832,10/13/2015,1510.40
```

My goal is to match the date and amount from CSV2 with the date and amount in CSV1, and write the reference from CSV2 to the reference column in the corresponding row.

This is a simplified view, as CSV2 actually contains many many more columns - these are just the relevant ones, so ideally I'd like to refer to them by header name or maybe index somehow?

Here's what I've attempted, but I'm a bit stuck.

```
require 'csv'

data1 = {}
data2 = {}

CSV.foreach("data1.csv", :headers => true, :header_converters => :symbol, :converters => :all) do |row|
  data1[row.fields[0]] = Hash[row.headers[1..-1].zip(row.fields[1..-1])]
end

CSV.foreach("data2.csv", :headers => true, :header_converters => :symbol, :converters => :all) do |row|
  data2[row.fields[0]] = Hash[row.headers[1..-1].zip(row.fields[1..-1])]
end

data1.each do |data1_row|
    data2.each do |data2_row|
        if (data1_row['comparitive'] == data2_row['comparitive'])
            puts data1_row['identifier'] + data2_row['column_thats_important_and_wanted']
        end
    end
end
```

Result:

```
22:in `[]': no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)
```

I've also tried:

```
CSV.foreach('data2.csv') do |data2|
    CSV.foreach('data1.csv') do |data1|
        if (data1[3] == data2[4])
            data1[1] << data2[1]
            puts "Change made!"
        else
            puts "nothing changed."
        end
    end
end
```

This however did not match anything inside the if statement, so perhaps not the right approach?

Comment: Sure that makes sense but... where is your code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see "[ask]". I'm sure you have tried to solve this, so please show the minimum code and data necessary to demonstrate your question. Without that we will have to guess and play 20 questions with you to understand what you have tried, which wastes all our time. To directly answer your question, there isn't a magic method to compare two columns, that's why we write code, to describe to the computer how to do it.

Comment: My apologies - I posted the question before I'd even accomplished getting anything useful written. I was still in the process of trying to figure out how to parse, but the method of comparing across csvs still eluded me. I've managed to rework it so I'm only comparing one column from each, and then trying to grab another column from the second and put into the first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

```
data1 = CSV.read('data1.csv')
data2 = CSV.read('data2.csv')

data2.each do |data2|
    data1.each do |data1|
        if (data1[5] == data2[4])
            data1[1] = data2[1]
            puts "Change made!"
            puts data1
        end
    end
end

File.open('referenced.csv','w'){ |f| f << data1.map(&:to_csv).join("")}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [headers](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-i-headers) method should help you match columns--from there it's a matter of parsing and writing the modified data back out to a file.